# How to split and store a const char* without using namespace std and string library?

Tags: c++, c

I have a const char* variable "str" which can be like the following one:

```
const char* str ="/v1/AUTH_abb52a71-fc76-489b-b56b-732b66bf50b1/images/bhs";
```

I have to split this `str` variable and store them in an array which is like `char a[256]`. But I want to split by detecting every slash(`/`). I mean I want to store `v1`,`AUTH_abb52a71-fc76-489b-b56b-732b66bf50b1` etc. Problem is that in this project I'm not allowed to use string library and namespace std, so I can't use `istringstream`. I'm only allowed to use `string.h` and `stdio.h`. So how can I do that within this limitations?

Comment: [Use strtok](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strtok/)

Comment: So, this isn't a C++ question?

Comment: You can use the C++ `std::string` functions too, or boost, seeing as how it's tagged C++.

Comment: Actually this project is indeed in C++ but with limitations. We are not allowed to use std in this.So I am having to cope with it. Otherwise I know how to do it with istringstream. But anyways, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  const char* yourStr;
  char str[1000];
  strncpy(str, yourStr, sizeof(str));
  char* parts[100] = {0};
  unsigned int index = 0;
  parts[index] = strtok(str,"/");

  while(parts[index] != 0)
  {
    ++index;
    parts[index] = strtok(0, "/");
  }
```

Answer (score 6):

strcpy(), then strtok().

Or do it the really basic way by iterating through the array.

Is this homework?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `strtok` function, which splits string into tokens. You can set « delim » with « / » value.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "string.h"


int main()
{
    char str [] ="/v1/AUTH_abb52a71-fc76-489b-b56b-732b66bf50b1/images/bhs";

    char* token_pointer;
    token_pointer = strtok(str, "/");

    while(NULL != token_pointer)
    {
            //handle your token
        printf("%s \n", token_pointer);
        token_pointer = strtok(NULL, "/");    
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Run it. Check the console.

Hope it helps!

Cheers ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar post [strtok - how avoid new line to and put to array of strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5156119/strtok-how-avoid-new-line-to-and-put-to-array-of-strings), if you go through you will find a great answer.

an excerpt code from there

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
...
void split(char *str, char **splitstr) 
{      
  char *p;      
  int i=0;      

  p = strtok(str,",");      
  while(p!= NULL)      
  {                
    printf("%s", p);
    splitsr[i] = malloc(strlen(p) + 1);
    if (splitstr[i])
      strcpy(splitstr[i], p);
    i++;
    p = strtok (NULL, ",");       
  } 
}
```